# Python class mock. How can I get mock-class method calls information

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class named *Client* providing some service by its *getResponse* method. This class is used by other classes.
I make unit testing for class *Driver* who uses the *Client* class.
By using mock.patch, I replace the *Client* class by mock class called *MockClient*
which has the same *getResponse* method returning some predefined values.
It works great. But now I want to test parameters the *getRsponse* method was called with.
I want to do it by using the *assert_has_calls* method.
Did not find how to do it. Please advice.

Class under test:

```
# Driver and its Client

class Driver:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.client = Client()

    def call(self, param):
        return self.client.getResponse(param)


class Client:
    def getResponse(self, param):
        return 'original'
```

This is the Test class with the mock class:

```
import unittest
import mock

import driver
from driver import Driver 
from driver import Client


class MockClient:
    def getResponse(self,param):
        return 'mock class' 


class TestIt(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_client = mock.patch('driver.Client',create=True, new=MockClient)
        self.mock_client.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_client.stop()

    def test_call(self):
        driver = Driver()
        result = driver.call('test')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'mock class')
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert_has_calls` expects a list of `call` objects that it can compare to.
You can get a `call` object by calling the [`mock.call`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock.call) helper function with your expected arguments and keyword arguments.

This example is [straight from the documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) and illustrates the usage quite well:

```
mock = Mock(return_value=None)
mock(1)
mock(2)
mock(3)
mock(4)
calls = [call(2), call(3)]
mock.assert_has_calls(calls)
calls = [call(4), call(2), call(3)]
mock.assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jbaiter, I saw this documentation and what I do not understand is how can I access the actual mock object.
I have this *mock_client* that I got from the patch function, there is a mock object created instead of the real Client object,
but I can not access the called method. I probably miss something important.